# Reactivity vue not rendering data with a method

Tags: arrays, state, rendering, splice, vue-reactivity

```
    <template>
    <div
        v-for="(a, i) in arr"
        :key="i"
        :checked="a"
        @click="toggleItem(i)"
        class="checkbox"
    >
    <div class="out">{{ arr }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                arr: [true, false, true, false, true, true, true],
            };
        },
        methods: {
            toggleItem(index) {
                this.arr.splice(index, 1, !index);
            }
        };
</script>
```

I wonder why the array arr is not rerendered in the template, probably because of the vue reactivity issues ?

I would like to receive rerendered {{arr}} in the template with opposite array items, changed from true to false and false to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index is a number, so given this line of code:

```js
this.arr.splice(index, 1, !index);
```

If say `index` = 3, then `!index` = false (so says JavaScript when you negate any number), meaning the line of code can be simplified to:

```js
this.arr.splice(index, 1, false);
```

Instead you need to specify the *index of the array*:

```js
this.arr.splice(index, 1, !this.arr[index])
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/fox0zts4/2/) example.

Comment: Thanks, very usefull, but now the click seems to change all of the arrays items at a time to an opposite state, not changing only the ciicked checkbox element of an array.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't very clear to me from your original code that that was what you were going for.  You probably want your `@click` on the inner div, and also should display the `a` element of the `v-for` instead of the full `arr` array every loop.  I've updated my answer and the sandbox.